# Firebird date concatention change date format

Tags: date, firebird, concatenation

For few days I'm having troubles with dates in Firebird query. I'm trying to concat 3 dates in one field in select statement.

Build up this to test it:

```
select 
data_wyst, data_sp, data_pop,
data_wyst ||' | '|| data_sp ||' | '|| data_pop
from rv_sp_dok
```

result is:

```
2015-12-14; 2015-12-14; 2015-12-31; 14-DEC-2015 | 14-DEC-2015 | 31-DEC-2015
2015-12-31; 2015-12-31; null; null
2015-12-31; 2015-12-31; 2015-12-31; 31-DEC-2015 | 31-DEC-2015 | 31-DEC-2015
```

So when one date is null then whole concat is null, and date format changed from 'YYYY-MM-DD' to 'DD-MM-YYYY'. Result concat should be:

```
2015-12-14; 2015-12-14; 2015-12-31; 2015-12-14 | 2015-12-14 | 2015-12-31
2015-12-31; 2015-12-31; null; 2015-12-31 | 2015-12-31 |
2015-12-31; 2015-12-31; 2015-12-31; 2015-12-31 | 2015-12-31 | 2015-12-31
```

Is there any way to prevent Firebird from changing date format when cast to string (except procedure converting date2string)?

//EDIT:
Seems to best way is procedure that will convert date to string:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE DATE2STRING (DataIN Date)
    returns (DataOut Varchar(10))
    AS 
      declare variable y Varchar(4);
      declare variable m Varchar(2);
      declare variable d Varchar(2);
    begin
    IF (DataIn is null) then 
    BEGIN
        DataOut = '';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        y = Substring(Extract(Year FROM DataIn) FROM 1 FOR 4);
        m = Substring(Extract(Month FROM DataIn)+100 FROM 2 FOR 2);
        d = Substring(Extract(Day FROM DataIn)+100 FROM 2 FOR 2);

        DataOut = y || '-' || m || '-' || d;
    END
    SUSPEND;
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To concat fields which might have `NULL`s use [coalesce](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-coalesce) function, ie

```sql
select 
data_wyst, data_sp, data_pop,
COALESCE(data_wyst, '') ||' | '|| COALESCE(data_sp, '') ||' | '|| COALESCE(data_pop, '')
from rv_sp_dok
```

To control the date format without using any external functions (which `date2string` is, AFAIK) you can use the [extract](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-extract) function, ie

```sql
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM data_pop) ||'-'|| EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data_pop)||'-'|| EXTRACT(DAY FROM data_pop)
```

Comment: Well didn't find better solution for now so it's extract or procedure that will do extract.
Still thinking why firebird change this when date is cast :/

Comment: @Jerry1333 Change what? The date format of the uncast fields are handled **client side** by the application showing that date, the cast fields are converted **server side** to string. The fact the entire string becomes null if one of them is null is because that is how SQL defines the concatenation operator (`||`).